# How to add delay in dispatch job in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, jobs, dispatch

I tried to do all of these:

Attempt 1:

```
DispatchWpAutoNewTaskJob::dispatch($payload)->delay(now()->addSeconds(10));
```

Attempt 2:

```
$when = now()->addSeconds(10);
dispatch(new DispatchWpAutoNewTaskJob($payload))->later($when);
```

Attempt 3:

```
dispatch(new DispatchWpAutoNewTaskJob($payload))->delay(now()->addSeconds(10));
```

But it all returns an error similar to this:

```
[stacktrace]
#0 /www/wwwroot/zz.com.test/app/Http/Controllers/Api/WpAutoWebhookController.php(63): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bus\\PendingDispatch->delay()
#1 /www/wwwroot/zz.com.test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\WpAutoWebhookController->handleWebhook()
```

Laravel version:
Laravel Framework 9.52.10

Attempt 1:

```
DispatchWpAutoNewTaskJob::dispatch($payload)->delay(now()->addSeconds(10));
```

Attempt 2:

```
$when = now()->addSeconds(10);
dispatch(new DispatchWpAutoNewTaskJob($payload))->later($when);
```

Attempt 3:

```
dispatch(new DispatchWpAutoNewTaskJob($payload))->delay(now()->addSeconds(10));
```

I am expecting that the job will be dispatch with a delay and it should be non-blocking. I already setup the redis and it is working. My only problem is the delay.

**Note that the codes inside the job are actually working, but without any delays. I wanna add non-blocking delay**

Comment: Does your job class uses Illuminate\Bus\Queueable?

Comment: Please share with us your job class `DispatchWpAutoNewTaskJob`.